# How to create postgresql database image file for docker on windows?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I installed docker in my windows operating system. And now I want to install postgresql database on docker, but I couldn't find any image file for windows. Could any one tell me how to create an image file for postgresql or how to get postgesql file for windows from docker hub? Please share the documents if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), in my opinion, images are the same between Win and linux. The difference is your environment, you run commands from a docker VM.
But commands docker are the same.

Comment: Thanks but its not working. showing the error PS C:\Users\pc> docker pull postgres
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries

Comment: Thank you kilian. i found a postgres windows image for docker.